# How to get a Bootstrap scroll animation working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the bug when scroll the website I don't see the navbar-Items changing. I have added the `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#MyScroll"` to the body and I added the links to the nav-Items but only the last item gets toggled.I read some other bug reports but they weren't very helpful.

What should I do?

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap-CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Jquery-UI-CSS -->
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Jquery-UI -->
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .myapp {
        font-size: 200%;
      }
      
      .email {
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      
      #Slide1 {
        background-image: url(http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Awesome-Wallpaper.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
      }
      
      #Slide1 h1,
      #Slide1 p,
      #Slide1 h3 {
        color: white;
      }
      
      #img {
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      
      #Slide2 {
        padding: 20px;
      }
      
      #Download {
        background-color: #99ccff;
        padding-top: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
      }
      
      #img2 {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#MyScroll">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" id="MyScroll">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Mobile Version -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>
          <a class="myapp navbar-brand" href="#">MyApp</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Mobile Version Ende -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#Slide1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Slide2">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Download">Download the App</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" aria-describedby="einfaches-addon1">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="einfaches-addon1">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log in</button>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center text-success" id="Slide1">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>My Awesome App!</h1>
        <h3>This is why you should download this fantastic App</h3>
        <p>Some more information about the App? You can get more facts here:</p>
        <p><b>Intrested? Join our mailing list!</b></p>
        <div class="email input-group col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-5">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="einfaches-addon1">@</span>
          <input for="buttonmail" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" aria-describedby="einfaches-addon1">
        </div>
        <p><a id="buttonmail" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Senden</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Second Slide -->
    <div class="text-center container" id="Slide2">
      <div>
        <h2>Why this App is so Awesome</h2>
        <h4>Summary of the app's awesomness</h4>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="row">
          <!-- First View -->
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img id="img" src="">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Vorschaubild-Titel</h3>
                <p>Beste App überhaupt</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Second View -->
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img id="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494249465471-5655b7878482?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=191559dc1cae3f8967d568dfd8a77093&w=1000&q=80">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Vorschaubild-Titel</h3>
                <p>Beste App überhauptLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam etLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                  sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam etLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                  ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Third View -->
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img id="img" src="http://www.backgroundimageshd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/1920x1080-Wallpaper-girl-face8.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Vorschaubild-Titel</h3>
                <p>Beste App überhaupt</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Download" class="text-center">

      <h1>Download the App now!</h1>
      <h3>Really, how can I get the App?</h3>
      <a href=""><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/call-of-mini-infinity/images/6/64/Ec6a786d_available-on-iphone-app-store-logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20150705143812" width="200px"></a>
      <br>
      <a href=""><img id="img2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Get_it_on_Google_play.svg/1280px-Get_it_on_Google_play.svg.png" width="200px"></a>

    </div>



    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
    </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working here, though I swapped in the CDN links I use for SO. I suggest you verify your links. Also, be mindful that some jQueryUI components conflict with Bootstrap 3.x

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html>

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      .myapp {
        font-size: 200%;
      }
      
      .email {
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      
      #Slide1 {
        background-image: url(http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Awesome-Wallpaper.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
      }
      
      #Slide1 h1,
      #Slide1 p,
      #Slide1 h3 {
        color: white;
      }
      
      #img {
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      
      #Slide2 {
        padding: 20px;
      }
      
      #Download {
        background-color: #99ccff;
        padding-top: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
      }
      
      #img2 {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#MyScroll">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" id="MyScroll">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Mobile Version -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>
          <a class="myapp navbar-brand" href="#">MyApp</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Mobile Version Ende -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#Slide1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Slide2">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Download">Download the App</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" aria-describedby="einfaches-addon1">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="einfaches-addon1">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log in</button>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center text-success" id="Slide1">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>My Awesome App!</h1>
        <h3>This is why you should download this fantastic App</h3>
        <p>Some more information about the App? You can get more facts here:</p>
        <p><b>Intrested? Join our mailing list!</b></p>
        <div class="email input-group col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-5">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="einfaches-addon1">@</span>
          <input for="buttonmail" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" aria-describedby="einfaches-addon1">
        </div>
        <p><a id="buttonmail" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Senden</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Second Slide -->
    <div class="text-center container" id="Slide2">
      <div>
        <h2>Why this App is so Awesome</h2>
        <h4>Summary of the app's awesomness</h4>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="row">
          <!-- First View -->
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img id="img" src="">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Vorschaubild-Titel</h3>
                <p>Beste App überhaupt</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Second View -->
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img id="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494249465471-5655b7878482?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=191559dc1cae3f8967d568dfd8a77093&w=1000&q=80">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Vorschaubild-Titel</h3>
                <p>Beste App überhauptLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam etLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                  sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam etLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                  ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Third View -->
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img id="img" src="http://www.backgroundimageshd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/1920x1080-Wallpaper-girl-face8.jpg">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Vorschaubild-Titel</h3>
                <p>Beste App überhaupt</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Download" class="text-center">

      <h1>Download the App now!</h1>
      <h3>Really, how can I get the App?</h3>
      <a href=""><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/call-of-mini-infinity/images/6/64/Ec6a786d_available-on-iphone-app-store-logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20150705143812" width="200px"></a>
      <br>
      <a href=""><img id="img2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Get_it_on_Google_play.svg/1280px-Get_it_on_Google_play.svg.png" width="200px"></a>

    </div>



    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
    </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks I found the problem.Do you work with bootstrap 4?

Comment: Both actually.  Things always seem to be in a constant state of upgrade.  Good for us :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I needed to run in the beginning. Do not know why it is working now but Problem is solved.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


                <!-- Jquery-UI-CSS -->
        <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <!-- Jquery-UI -->
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <!-- Bootstrap-CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
                <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
            .myapp{
                font-size: 200%;
            }
            .email{
                margin-bottom: 8px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            #Slide1{
                background-image: url(http://hdwpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Awesome-Wallpaper.jpg);
                background-size: cover;
            }
            #Slide1 h1, #Slide1 p, #Slide1 h3{
                color: white;
            }
            #img{
                border-radius: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            #Slide2{
                padding: 20px;
            }
            #Download{
                background-color: #99ccff;
                padding-top: 200px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 700px;
            }
            #img2{
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
        </style>
```